# Data difference between two database

Tags: sql-server-2005

I am working on SQL Server 2005. I have took the backup and restore the database. I just wanted to know is there any way I can check whether the data between these two database are diffent. or any script that I can run or check [ could be table by table] to see if any new row added or modified.

**EDITED**

For example - I have to check the data difference from Database 1 Table_User to Database 2 Table_User.

Thanks

Comment: Are the databases big in terms of number of tables and rows?

Comment: only 2-3 tables are big, around 10 thousand rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the built-in command line tool TableDiff.exe:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162843(SQL.90).aspx

It performs row by row comparisons along with column-level comparisons.  Here's an article that walks through how to use it:

http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3594926/SQL-Server-2005-TableDiff-Utility.htm

And another  (with a link to a GUI that you can download):

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/03/03/60125.aspx

This would be on a table by table basis - but it's free and already installed for you since you have SQL Server 2005 installed.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Do i need to open Microsoft .NET Framework v2.0 SDK command prompt ????

Or

Run > cmd

Comment: Should be installed here: `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\COM\TableDiff.exe` (may differ based on how you installed sql server).  Just a basic run > cmd should do it, I believe.  It's part of the client tools part of the install.

Answer (score 0):

you can use sql compare and sql data compare.(red-gate.com)
or you can use sql delta.(sqldelta.com)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to track what are changes in your restored database comparing to that before it was restored. If so, I hope this may be helpful.

```
ALTER DATABASE yourdatabasename SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON (CHANGE_RETENTION = 2 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON);
GO
USE yourdatabasename;
GO
ALTER TABLE Person.Person ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING
 WITH (TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON);
GO
```

Comment: what will be the output of this ?? I mean, I afraid that it will not update any one of the database.. Is it going to update my database ???

Comment: No, it won't. It just track what has been changed between two databases

Comment: I have used this 

ALTER DATABASE StudentOld SET CHANGE_TRACKING = ON 
(CHANGE_RETENTION = 20 DAYS, AUTO_CLEANUP = ON);
 GO USE studentNew; 
 GO ALTER TABLE T_Member 
ENABLE CHANGE_TRACKING WITH 
(TRACK_COLUMNS_UPDATED = ON);
 GO

I am getting below error

A fatal scripting error occurred.
Incorrect syntax was encountered while parsing GO.

Comment: Wait, are you trying to compare two totally different tables or are you tracking the changes of your old table? My answer only works for second issue.